# Unable to locate element using Xpath using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have tried several ways to locate the elements of the form on the [webpage ] using selenium in python but I unable to do so.

This is the code I have tried (only for "Name" column) along with several ways to input the xpath as suggested in other answers.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://shooliniuniversity.com/how-to-apply")
driver.maximize_window()

# fill the form
Name = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='Name']" )))
Name.send_keys('John Doe')


# time.sleep(2)
# driver.quit()
```

I also tried using `By.NAME, "Name"` and `By.ID, 'input text'`

Kindly help and suggest me how shall I correct this?
Also, I am believing that the suggestion can be applied on all the other fields of the form too.

Comment: the fields are in an iframe. you need to switch to it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your locator strategy was all correct. Only thing you were missing was handling the `iframe`. As this element is wrapped within an `iframe`, you need to switch into it first, then perform the next actions.

Try the below code:

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//iframe)[1]")
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(iframe))
Name = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='Name']" )))
Name.send_keys('John Doe')
```

**Output:**

[image]

**NOTE:**
Once you are done with all actions within the `iframe` and want to action on the other part of the page, then you need to switch back to main content using below code:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```