# Unable to locate span element "Users" with selenium-Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

HTML code is in enclosed image
[html code snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIxiN.png)

Locating span element "Users" failed with below error

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(),'Users')]"}

Tried locating "Users" tab with below code

```
users = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Users')]")
```

Comment: Can you please, as described in [selenium-webdriver tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) add tag for language you're using? It's Python, right? It would also help if you could post relevant HTML snippet as text rather than image, as per [ask]: "DO NOT post images of code, **data**, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question."

Comment: Share the URL of the application if its not a sensitive info.

Comment: @Shawn This is our internal web application so can't be reachable outside our VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons for this `Exception`. Without accessing the actual URL, its hard to tell the root cause. Below are few possible options you can try:

**1.** First check if you can locate the element by inspecting the DOM.

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> key, and then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. Paste the XPATH expression `//span[contains(text(),'Users')]`. If it locates one element then you are good, if it locates more than one element or locates zero elements you need to modify your XPATH expression

**2.** Check for the presence of `iframe`, if the desired element is within an `iframe`, then you need to switch into the iframe first. Refer below link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75812495/7598774

**3.** If there is no `iframe`, then try to perform action by inducing waits.

```
users = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Users')]" )))
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn for the inputs!
Second point in your post help to trace this problem further & found multiple "iframe".
Issue resolved after switching into corresponding "iframe" before locating "Users" element.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is correct. Use Selenium waits and try to find. If the element is not interactable you will get NoSuchElementException. To avoid this, selenium provides waits. Instead you can try with Thread.sleep() to wait for sometime.

Comment: Adding delay is not working with same error of NoSuchElementException & I believe if the element is not interactable then probably exception would be "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException"