# How can I find this element?

Tags: performance, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

Launch and Login requests are happening and from next request getting below error

[image: Code]

Getting error

```
Target exception: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="root"]/div/div/main/form/div[1]/div/div/div/label/div[2]/input"}
```

Java 1.8.0_3612, Edge 111.0.1661.62, JMeter 5.5, JMeter plugin manager 1.8.

Comment: Can you share the URL of the application? or at least the HTML in the text format?

Comment: Thanks Shawn, URL is 
 https://web.automation.itmportal.co.uk

Comment: Unfortunately with just the URL and without user credentials to log into the system, there is very less help you can expect. Clearly the issue is that your code is not able to locate any web element with this XPATH expression `//*[@id="root"]/div/div/main/form/div1/div/div/div/label/div[2]/input`. You need to sort that out first. Check this answer this may help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75865161/7598774

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you chose `java` as the scripting language. Please don't because it's not a real "java", it's [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) interpreter which is not 100% Java compatible.

Consider switching to `groovy` language and I think the error should go away.

Moreover [Groovy is the recommended scripting language since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) mainly because it has [better performance comparing to other scripting options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter).

Going forward please [don't post code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), it will be easier for the community to reproduce your issue and come up with the comprehensive solution

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. This should have been a comment. Switching from "java" to Groovy isn't going to make that locator work.

Comment: This IS the answer to the ORIGINAL question, I'm not hitting F5 continually on every SO question to check if there are any updates so I could immediately update the answer.

Comment: Look at the edit history... the core of the question has not changed and this is still not the answer. As I said before, `Switching from "java" to Groovy isn't going to make that locator work.` and the locator IS the problem.

Comment: My dear little "selenium developer", my original answer was for `n inline evaluation of: ``import openqa.selenium` error.

Comment: So you think being insulting is going to make you sound smarter? The title when you answered the question was the full error message referring to the  `NoSuchElementException` and nothing more. The first line in the question itself was a repeat of the title, exactly the same exception message. You skipped over the obvious error message (listed twice) and went to the code dump which started on the second line of the question. If you'd have bothered to actually read the code included, you'd have seen that line 8, where the error message came from, was a `.findElement` call using the bad locator.

Comment: So I say again... `Switching from "java" to Groovy isn't going to make that locator work.` You read the question wrong. The locator is STILL the problem.