# Typing on an Input element textbox with selenium python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, web-crawler, timeoutexception

Typing in an Input element textbox in Python Selenium is showing TimeoutException. Here is the code.

```
#provides access to the webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
#allows interraction with elements of the webpage
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

import time

#initilize a webdriver object
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.example.com/")

#type in textbox 
textbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[class='up-input']")))
textbox.clear()
textbox.send_keys("hello World")
```

Here is the element it is trying to click on

```
<input data-v-069d3018="" data-test="milestone-description" type="text" aria-describedby="milestone-description-1-error" aria-label="Description 1" class="up-input">
```

Trying with `data-test` in both XPath and CSS selector doesn't work

```
textbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[data-test='milestone-description']")))
textbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "input[data-test='milestone-description']")))`
```

Trying with `type` in both XPath and CSS selector doesn't work

```
textbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='text']")))
textbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "input[type='text']")))
```

Trying with `aria-describedby` in both XPath and CSS selector doesn't work

```
textbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[aria-describedby='milestone-description-1-error']")))
textbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "input[aria-describedby='milestone-description-1-error']")))
```

And trying with `aria-label` with both XPath and CSS selector doesn't work

```
textbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[aria-label='Description 1']")))
textbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "input[aria-label='Description 1']")))
```

The expectation was that the code will be able to find the element and enter the text with one of these but no luck. As it's a pretty website with a lot going on I want to make sure the selectors are reliable so updates to the website don't stop the code.

Comment: Can you share the URL if that is public? If not, check the below link if that helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/75865161/7598774. Check if there is an `iframe`

Comment: Your XPaths are not correct, e.g. `(By.XPATH, "input[data-test='milestone-description']")` should be `(By.XPATH, "//input[@data-test='milestone-description']")`. Your CSS selectors look fine though so it shouldn't be that. My guess is that the INPUT you are looking for is inside an IFRAME or shadow-root.

Comment: you may also want to use expected condition of presenceOfElement instead of toBeClickable.

Comment: hi thanks for the replies... just a couple of questions.... 1) what is an iframe or shadow root? 2) How do i check if there is an iframe or shadow-root? 3) If there is an iframe or shadow-root what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the code is opening up a new tab if it is then use

```
  # Click on a link that opens a new tab
  driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

to switch to the new tab