# How to find xpath of a textfield and fill with data?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

im testing an application with seleniun using java,
and trying to find xpath of a textfield.

Any help, thank you

```
<div class="mat-form-field">
 <input matinput class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-monitored" required id="mat-input-5" name="threshold-2" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
```

i tried:

```
xpath = ("//div[@class='mat-form-field']")
xpath = ("//div[@id='mat-input-5']")
xpath = ("//div[@id='mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-monitored']")
```

none is working for me.
error received is:
no such element: Unable to located element

There is also a text label for the textfield which is:

```
<label class='mat-form-field-label ng-tn>' id='mat-form-field-label-100' for='mat-input-10' aria-owns='mat-input-20'>
<!---->
<mat-label class='ng-tns-c87 ng-star-inserted'>Enter value here please<mat-label class/>
```

So i tried:
`xpath = "//div[contains(text(), 'Enter value here please']"`

error received is:
no such element: Unable to located element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XPATH expression:

```
//input[@id='mat-input-5']
```

Or this:

```
//input[@name='threshold-2']
```

1. First check if you can manually inspect the browser and locate the element using above XPATH expression, if yes,
2. Try to apply `waits`. See code below:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20)).until(
                ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='mat-input-5']"))).click();
```

3. Even after this if you get `Unable to locate element`, then check for the presence of an IFRAME, if there is an iframe, you need to switch the context to IFRAME first
   Refer this link if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75865161/7598774

Comment: ok with console, i am able to locate the element,i use the same in java, it cant find find, im going to try your suggestion, thank you.@Shawn

Comment: it worked with this: //input[@name='threshold-2']