# What can I use to address v-if, css selector or xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

What can I use to address v-if, css selector or xpath?

```
div class="el-table-box" v-if="!specialAnnounce">
```

Comment: How can someone with your rep ask a question like this? Did you even search stackoverflow before asking?

Comment: How can I write the code? content1=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,  ".el-table-box[v-if='!specialAnnounce']"))), it doesn't work

Comment: Try changing your xpath expression to `div[class="el-table-box"][v-if="!specialAnnounce"]`.

Comment: Cell In[1], line 25
    parent_div = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.XPATH, "div[class="el-table-box"][v-if="!specialAnnounce"]"))
                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<div class="el-table-box" v-if="!specialAnnounce">
```

You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.el-table-box[v-if$='specialAnnounce']")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='el-table-box' and contains(@v-if, 'specialAnnounce')]")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  ```

Comment: ---
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 21
     19 # Wait for the announcement elements to be visible
     20 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # Adjust the timeout value as needed
---> 21 announcement_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.el-table-box[v-if$='specialAnnounce']"))
     22 # Extract the latest announcements within 2 hours
     23 latest_announcements = []

TypeError: visibility_of_all_elements_located() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code, using `ExplicitWait` and `CSS` locator:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
announcement_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.el-table-box[v-if$='specialAnnounce']")))
```

Comment: TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 21
     19 # Wait for the announcement elements to be visible
     20 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # Adjust the timeout value as needed
---> 21 announcement_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.el-table-box[v-if$='!specialAnnounce']")))
     22 # Extract the latest announcements within 2 hours
     23 latest_announcements = []

Comment: Do you see any presence of an `<iframe>` in the HTML which is wrapping the desired element?

Comment: Follow the trouble shooting steps from this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75865161/7598774