# Can't click on element in selenium for login

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, xpath-2.0

I am trying to click on this element in selenium for login but it wont work for me. Here is the html code for it.

[image]

This is my code for it

```cs
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='otherTile']")).Click();
```

But it won't work. It gave me an error saying element not found.

Comment: Can you put the HTML snippet in as text rather than an image?

Comment: Is "driver" a parent or a child element of the "otherTile" div? And are there multiple divs with id "otherTile"?

Comment: Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75865161/7598774

Comment: The driver is the child element of the div

Comment: check if you have any iframes in your page. if you have it, first you need to switch to an iframe and then locate the element you need.