# Click on a tag using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on an element using Selenium but keep getting the error message `"selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element {"method":"partial link text","selector":"foo"}" .` Here is the element I want to click:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:toMove('0000172','c99','https://www.boo.com/usemn/co/UM_COJ_CIQ003.jsp','mainFrame','PT_FMJ_SFQ001.jsp');" onfocus="blur()">
    foo
</a>
```

And here is the code I'm using in Selenium:

```
link = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "foo")
```

Comment: I tried literally the same code and was able to get the element. For reference here is the code to test, I didn't include the imports
html_content = """
<html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
         <a href="#" onclick="javascript:toMove('0000172','c99','https://www.boo.com/usemn/co/UM_COJ_CIQ003.jsp','mainFrame','PT_FMJ_SFQ001.jsp');" onfocus="blur()">
    foo
</a>
     </body>
</html>
"""

html_bs64 = base64.b64encode(html_content.encode('utf-8')).decode()
driver.get("data:text/html;base64," + html_bs64)
link = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "foo")
print(link.text)

Comment: Check this answer if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75865161/7598774

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:toMove('0000172','c99','https://www.boo.com/usemn/co/UM_COJ_CIQ003.jsp','mainFrame','PT_FMJ_SFQ001.jsp');" onfocus="blur()">
    foo
</a>
```

To click on the element you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *partial_link_text*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "foo").click()
  ```
- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick*='mainFrame']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@onclick, 'mainFrame') and contains(., 'foo')]").click()
  ```

---

However, the desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the ***clickable*** element  you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "foo"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick*='mainFrame']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@onclick, 'mainFrame') and contains(., 'foo')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```