# How to locate a dynamic angular element in selenium web driver?

Tags: python, angular, selenium-webdriver

I have a page created using angular. I can write XPATH to an element in DevTool, but when I try the same XPath in selenium-webdriver, it doesn't work and ends with error `no such element: Unable to locate element`

What may be the issue? I heard about problem with frame, but I don't see any `<frame>` around the element in DOM.

I'm new to Selenium and appreciate any help!

I searched for similar topics but nothing helped

Here is what I see with `ctrl+U`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>plugins-...</title>
    <base href="..."/>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.420f7dc775fc291175a8.css"></head>
  <body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <script src="runtime.0e49e2b53282f40c8925.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills.ad58a8acf0ba34480cbf.js" defer></script><script src="main.4e89de4fb545d830ba25.js" defer></script></body>
</html>
```

This is the element I want to locate:

```
<input _ngcontent-ick-c114="" matinput="" type="search" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control field__input ng-tns-c19-2 cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored" id="mat-input-0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">
```

So I tried xpath `//input[@id='mat-input-0']` and it works fine in devtool, but not in selenium

Comment: Can you show us the `code` and `HTML` source for the element you are trying to locate ?

Comment: I put it in edit

Comment: I cant even locate to "app-root" element: `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//app-root")`

Comment: You need to inspect the element and share the HTML of the element which you are interested in. Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75865161/7598774.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The detail that you have provided is kind o confusing you are talking different things. If you are getting the error `no such element: Unable to locate element`
than try:

```
input_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="mat-input-0"]'))
```

***Import***

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

if the element is inside an `iframe`, you need to `switch` to the `iframe` first before locating the element. You can use the `driver.switchTo().frame()` method to switch to the `iframe`.