# Unable to reach a button even though it is in the screen and I am using an ID to locate it

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing my first selenium and python test and I am trying to click a button by doing the following :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()


driver.get("https://portal.sandbox.mechanized.ai/")
driver.maximize_window() 
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

email = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email')
password = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password')
loginBtn = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'login-button')
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
nextBtn = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'next-button')

email.send_keys("xxxxxx")
password.send_keys("xxxxx")
loginBtn.click()
nextBtn.click()
```

I can't do the second click even though I wait for it

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="next-button"]"}
```

It seems during the execution that I am not reaching that screen, but it goes so fast that I can't tell for sure. Is there any good practice that I am missing? Any strategy that I should be applying?

Comment: Add the `HTML` source for _next button_ looks like you are facing the error on this element

Comment: Check this answer if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75865161/7598774

Answer (score 0):

This might occur due to several reasons.

1. There is no such element to locate by Selenium -
   Use different locators such as ID, NAME, CLASS, XPATH
2. TimeOut Issue -
   You can keep a delay between two buttons where you do the actions, not in the tracing point.