# XPath expression to locate web element which is a dropdown

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am a little bit frustrated, because I searched for a web element in a `<table>` HTML, `by.XPATH` with `following-sibling`. But the system is unable to locate my element.

I want to change the dropdown value for email address labelled "katja@katja.com" from "Standard" to "Admin".

But the attribute `ID`'s value "role" is not unique. There are no unique attributes to locate the element.

The Table looks like this (there is no unique id or name I can search for:

```
 <tbody>            <tr id="0dca86a5-13d3-4ab5-a2e6-e75ab381dca9">
                    <td class="emailAddress">max@max.com</td>
                    <td class="role">
                    <form action="/echo/UserManagement/UpdateRole?userId=0dca86a5-13d3-4ab5-a2e6-e75ab381dca9&amp;accountReference=4711&amp;username=max%40max.com" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                        <div class="field-inline">
                        <select class="roles medium" id="role" name="role"><option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                            <option value="Standard">Standard</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="Basic">Basic</option>
                            <option value="Template">Template</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field-inline">
                            <button class="button button-primary save" type="submit">Save</button>
                            <noscript>
                                <button class="button button-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
                            </noscript>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    </td>
                    <td class="action">
                        <form action="/echo/UserManagement/RemoveUserFromAccount" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><input id="userId" name="userId" type="hidden" value="0a23788b-0ed6-401b-a11e-8004d34acf1a"><input id="usernameToRemove" name="usernameToRemove" type="hidden" value="max@max.com">
                            <input id="accountReference" name="accountReference" type="hidden" value="4711">
                            <button type="submit" class="button button-danger remove_user" data-confirm="true">Remove</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>           </tr>           <tr id="e5b128b5-75f9-4002-bcd9-11c8bc891d49">
                    <td class="emailAddress">john@john.com</td>
                    <td class="role">
                    <form action="/echo/UserManagement/UpdateRole?userId=e5b128b5-75f9-4002-bcd9-11c8bc891d49&amp;accountReference=4711&amp;username=john%40john.com" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                        <div class="field-inline">
                        <select class="roles medium" id="role" name="role"><option selected="selected" value="Admin">Admin</option>
                            <option value="Standard">Standard</option>
                            <option value="Basic">Basic</option>
                            <option value="Template">Template</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field-inline">
                            <button class="button button-primary save" type="submit">Save</button>
                            <noscript>
                                <button class="button button-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
                            </noscript>
                        </div>
                    </form>                    
                    </td>
                    <td class="action">
                    <form action="/echo/UserManagement/RemoveUserFromAccount" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><input id="userId" name="userId" type="hidden" value="f45a18fc-4903-4189-8cab-c158630373a3"><input id="usernameToRemove" name="usernameToRemove" type="hidden" value="john@john.com">
                        <input id="accountReference" name="accountReference" type="hidden" value="4711">
                        <button type="submit" class="button button-danger remove_user" data-confirm="true">Remove</button>
                    </form>    
                    </td>           </tr>           <tr id="5e356ca7-fa23-45a9-b7f3-c9e71ce5cb5f">
                    <td class="emailAddress">katja@katja.com</td>
                    <td class="role">
                    <form action="/echo/UserManagement/UpdateRole?userId=5e356ca7-fa23-45a9-b7f3-c9e71ce5cb5f&amp;accountReference=4711&amp;username=katja%40katja.com" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                        <div class="field-inline">
                        <select class="roles medium" id="role" name="role"><option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="Standard">Standard</option>
                            <option value="Basic">Basic</option>
                            <option value="Template">Template</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field-inline">
                            <button class="button button-primary save" type="submit">Save</button>
                            <noscript>
                                <button class="button button-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
                            </noscript>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    </td>
                    <td class="action">
                        <form action="/echo/UserManagement/RemoveUserFromAccount" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><input id="userId" name="userId" type="hidden" value="1c094ceb-13a7-41cf-b754-921ac15dd9dc"><input id="usernameToRemove" name="usernameToRemove" type="hidden" value="katja@katja.com">
                            <input id="accountReference" name="accountReference" type="hidden" value="4711">
                            <button type="submit" class="button button-danger remove_user" data-confirm="true">Remove</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>           </tr> </tbody>
```

My code trials:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[text()='katja@katja.com']/following-sibling::/form/select")
```

and

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[text()='katja@katja.com']/following-sibling::*[1]/form/select")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below XPath expression:

```
(//form[contains(@action,'katja.com')]//following::select)[1]
```

**Explanation:** The XPath expression selects the first `<select>` element that follows any `<form>` element with an `action` attribute containing the string "katja.com".

Code should look like:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//form[contains(@action,'katja.com')]//following::select)[1]"))
```

**UPDATE:** If you are getting `No Such Element Exception`, that could be due to more than one reason. Follow the trouble shooting steps in the below answer

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75865161/7598774

Comment: When I try with this I get:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: If you manually inspect the page and try to locate the element using the XPath in my answer, will it locate the element successfully?

Comment: Thank you very much for your Comment, I do not knowed that it is possible to search in the Developer Tools. Now I know. I found the Solution for me, it is:
find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[text()='@katja.com']//following::select")