Webpage Login with selenium
In a webpage I'd like to make the automatic login passing the user and password via Python.
I'm using this code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://10.50.20.10/")
time.sleep(5)
username = driver.find_element(By.ID,"Username")
password = driver.find_element_by_id(By.ID,"Password")

username.send_keys("admin")
password.send_keys("pass$")


driver.find_element(By.NAME,"Login").click()

with this code I see the webpage is properly opened but the code goes in error when trying to type/find the username:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\test.py", line 18, in <module>
    username = driver.find_element(By.ID,"Username")
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 741, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="Username"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.122); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7C0E47032+63090]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C0DB2C82]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C0C4EC65]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C0C9499D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C0C94ADC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C0CD5B37]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C0CB701F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C0CD3412]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C0CB6D83]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C0C883A8]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C0C89441]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7C12425AD+4238317]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7C127F70D+4488525]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7C12779EF+4456495]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7C0F20576+953270]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C0DBE54F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C0DB9224]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C0DB935B]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C0DA9B94]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFF415A7344+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFF42DC26B1+33]

I don't understand where the error is. The webpage is like this:

this is the html code I have:
<html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Christoph Lukas Lindtner">
    <meta name="designer" content="Christoph Lukas Lindtner">
    <meta name="description" content="eiCAB - This is 4G">
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <link rel="icon" href="/img/app/icons/favicon.png" type="image/png">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <title>HMI8462-TW • C0118828</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cbd179784e6e85707d5d648d84e84f25732d1e7e1594916ea75f3de455036850.css" type="text/css">
        <script type="application/javascript" src="4fa2c0563949d618857f54c5c23b5e66caad69ba2dc66ccaeeeb0e3fc7b622df.js"></script>
    <script src="blob:http://10.80.100.10/616fc941-ae19-4977-8979-c8633be146e3"></script></head>
<body class="st connected login" role="application" id="madpenguin"><div role="progressbar" class="orbit" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><canvas width="80" height="80"></canvas></div><div class="ui-workplace-overlay"></div><div role="main" style="height: 901px; width: 1365px;"><div role="toolbar" class="action-bar" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 869px; display: none;"><div role="button" class="action-control-box"><div class="label" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div><div role="img" class="action-back" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M18.5 12.5H7.3l5.2 5.4 -0.6 0.7L5.5 12l6.3-6.5 0.6 0.7 -5.2 5.4h11.2V12.5z" fill="#878787"></path></svg></div><div role="img" class="action-bar-icon"></div><div role="img" class="action-drawer-control" style="transform: translate3d(24px, 0px, 0px);"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#95A5A6" d="M18.5 13h-13v-2h13V13zM18.5 17h-13v2h13V17zM18.5 5h-13v2h13V5z"></path></svg></div></div><div class="action-bar-title" role="heading" aria-level="1"></div><div role="menu" class="action-menu"></div><div class="notification-bar"><div role="button" class="widget link online"><div class="label"></div></div><div role="button" class="widget-notifications widget"><div class="label" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div></div></div></div><div class="application-background"></div><div style="height: 901px; width: 1365px;"><div class="login-layout vertical" style="height: 901px; width: 1365px;"><div role="form" class="login-box" style="left: 443px; top: 192px;"><div class="logo vertical"></div><div class="device-name vertical">HMI8462-TW</div><div class="input-block vertical"><div role="textbox" aria-owns="n7ai" class=""><div class="label" id="93u8" style="">Username</div><input autocomplete="off" aria-labelledby="93u8" type="text"><textarea autocomplete="off" aria-labelledby="93u8" style="display: none;"></textarea></div><div role="textbox" aria-owns="1ir5" class=""><div class="label" id="uui4" style="">Password</div><input autocomplete="off" aria-labelledby="uui4" class="hidden" type="text"><textarea autocomplete="off" aria-labelledby="uui4" class="hidden" style="display: none;"></textarea></div><div role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="3ao1" class=""><div class="label" id="v6mg" style="">Select language</div><input type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-labelledby="v6mg" style="display: none;"><div class="value">English</div><div role="img" class="arrow"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#9E9E9E" d="M17 9.5l-4.4 4.9L12 15l-0.6-0.6L7 9.5 7.7 9l4.3 4.7L16.3 9 17 9.5z"></path></svg></div></div></div><div role="button" class="action-login vertical" style="left: 165px;"><div role="img" class="icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="tiny" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#95a5a6" d="M15.4 8.3h-1.6c0-1.4-0.8-2.6-1.8-2.6 -1 0-1.8 1.2-1.8 2.6H8.6c0-2.6 1.5-4.8 3.4-4.8C13.9 3.5 15.4 5.6 15.4 8.3zM17.1 9.8H6.9C6.3 10.4 6 11.3 6 12.2v4.8c0 2 1.6 3.6 3.6 3.6h4.8c2 0 3.6-1.6 3.6-3.6v-4.8C18 11.3 17.7 10.4 17.1 9.8zM10.4 17.2l1-1.7c-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.6-0.7-1.1 0-0.7 0.5-1.2 1.2-1.2 0.7 0 1.2 0.5 1.2 1.2 0 0.5-0.3 0.9-0.7 1.1l1 1.7H10.4z"></path></svg></div><div class="label" style="">Login</div></div><div class="login-status vertical"></div></div><div role="img" class="copyright" style="bottom: 40px; left: 683px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 100 24" enable-background="new 0 0 100 24" xml:space="preserve" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">













Info-HubDatabase ManagerSettingsUpdate SoftwareUser ManagementLogout
null

Please edit your post to include the HTML sourcecode of this webpage. My guess is that the element's ID is in fact not "Username" as it appears on the rendered webpage

ciao I had the same thought.I've attached an image of the html.I've tried with by.Id giving as research "93u8" and with by.Name giving "Username" but it is clear I'm making a mistake.

Do not share the HTML as image, share it as text. Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

edited with the code.

Replace driver.find_element(By.ID,"Username") with driver.find_element(By.ID,"93u8"), from the ID of the HTML element

username = driver.find_element(By.ID,"Username")

Above code is incorrect. There is no ID attribute with value 'Username'. Change the line as below, which uses XPath locator strategy.
# For username
username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[text()='Username']//following::input[1]")

# For password
password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[text()='Password']//following::input[1]")

# For Login button
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[text()='Login']").click()

UPDATE: With the HTML mark-up shared in the question, above XPath strategy should locate the element. If it still doesn't locate, and gives no such element exception, then check for presence of IFRAME.
Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75865161/7598774

I've tried and it doens't work

Check the updated answer. Also, share a little bit more of HTML not just that particular element.

added more code. sorry but I'm newbie of html/coding

Check the answer and try now. I have changed the XPath expression to locate input node rather than div node.
